# What is a good way for my webapp to identify the first visitor to a page that may have many simultaneous viewers, even if s/he refreshes the page

Tags: reactjs, websocket

I have a React.js webapp that utilizes websockets. There is a page in the app that handles data editing and multiple visitors may arrive at the page.  The first visitor to that page needs to be given special access to page components for the editing.

What is a good way to continue identifying this user and continue the special access, even if that first visitor refreshes his/her browser and given that other users may refresh as well?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the users are anonymous:

Middleware on routes to check if they are the first user.

If the user doesn't already have a token, I'd create a JWT when the websocket is opened that is a unique ID and store it as a cookie on each user. In the route on the server side, I will have a middleware do a check for the first user. If the first user doesn't exist, take the unique ID and store it. If it does exist, compare the token to check if it matches.

Unless the user deletes the token, they'll still have access to the page on refresh.